# open a file from resources - Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i am trying to open an xml file in my java class but i am getting this nullpointerexception, my directory structure for the project in eclipse is;

```
-proj-master
->src->users.package->includeusers.java
->resources->users->users.xml
```

So basically i am trying to open users.xml in includeusers.java class and it can be seen that resources is outside src folder, please guide.

```
File fXmlFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("../resources/users/users.xml").getFile());
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on `getResources`. The directory name is `resources` (with 'r') but you have `resouces` (without 'r') in the constructor argument.

Comment: thnx for pointing that out, actually i don't have this typo in my code its just that i edited my code after posting my question here so made a typo otherwise its fine in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out, had to just include the folder in class path.